# How to check if an array is in another array?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, indexof

For example,

var grades = [[English, A] , [Math, B] , [Geography, C]];

var englishGrade = [English, A];

Logger.log(grades.indexOf(englishGrade));
// This returns -1 and not 0.

So i was wondering if there is another way to check if an array is inside another array.

As shown in the above example, I've tried .indexOf(), but I also tried .includes(). Both doesn't work the way as I intend it to work.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function  isAInB(a = [1,2,3], b = [5,4,3,2,0]) {
  Logger.log(a.every(e => b.includes(e)))
  return a.every(e => b.includes(e));
}
```

[default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

[Array.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

[Array.includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript does not do a deep comparison of objects. Instead, it compares their references. Two objects are only equal if the variables holding them are actually pointing to the same object. As a result

```
{} === {}
```

returns `false`.

If you want to check if one array is contained within another, you'll have to do some searching. This is okay for small arrays, but if you have really big ones, it can be slow. Here's one possible solution.

```
const grades = [[English, A] , [Math, B] , [Geography, C]];
const englishGrade = [English, A];
grades.find( grade => grade[0] === englishGrade[0] && grade[1] === englishGrade[1] );
```

This will return the array `[English, A]` if it's found, and undefined if it's not. This solution clearly gets out of hand the more you have to compare, though.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.some()` and `Array.every()`, like this:

```js
function test() {
  const grades = [['English', 'A'], ['Math', 'B'], ['Geography', 'C']];
  const englishGrade = ['English', 'A'];
  console.log(arrayIncludesArray_(grades, englishGrade));
}


/**
* Determines whether arrayToSearch includes a subarray where every
* element exactly matches the same element in the searchFor array.
*
* @param {Object[][]} arrayToSearch The 2D array to search.
* @param {Object[]} searchFor The 1D array to search for.
* @return {Boolean} true if at least one subarray in arrayToSearch exactly matches searchFor.
*/
function arrayIncludesArray_(arrayToSearch, searchFor) {
  if (!Array.isArray(arrayToSearch) || !Array.isArray(arrayToSearch[0])) {
    throw new Error('arrayIncludesArray_ requires that arrayToSearch is a 2D array.');
  }
  if (!Array.isArray(searchFor) || Array.isArray(searchFor[0])) {
    throw new Error('arrayIncludesArray_ requires that searchFor is a 1D array.');
  }
  return arrayToSearch.some(row => row.every((value, index) => value === searchFor[index]));
}
```